# Ruby 2.0 + Rails 4 + Devise 3.1.1 logout issue

Tags: ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

if I click on the logout button i get this error: inspected result must be ASCII only or use the same encoding with default external

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.

  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
  end

end
```

Link:

```
<%= link_to "Logout", logout_path, title: "Logout", method: :delete %>
```

Routes:

```
devise_scope :user do
  get 'register', to: 'devise/registrations#new', as: 'register'
  get 'login', to: 'devise/sessions#new', as: 'login'
  delete 'logout', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: 'logout'
end
```

I have no idea where the problem is.

If I remove this 3 lines then it works but i can't register a new user:

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email) }
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
```

Thank you!

Comment: there seems to be an issue with your content encoding of strings. looks like you mix ASCII and and other encodings.

Comment: all my documents are saved in UTF-8.

Comment: were you able to fix the issue? I'm getting the same error and none of the answers below are helping

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :username
```

And if you need yet another field, add a line like the one above

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is the cause but I noticed that you don't allow a password to be whitelisted upon sign in. I assume that you would want that because you a password in the sign up and account update. It should look like this

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password) }
```